# Image cropping system doesn't work with png or gif but works with jpg

Tags: php

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

$dst_x = 0;
$dst_y = 0;
$src_x = $_POST['left'];
$src_y = $_POST['top'];
$dst_w = $_POST['width'];
$dst_h = $_POST['height'];
$src_w = $_POST['width'];
$src_h = $_POST['height'];

$file_name = 'test.gif';

$allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
$file_extension= explode('.', $file_name); 
$file_extn= strtolower(end($file_extension));

$dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w,$dst_h);

if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) == 'jpg, jpeg'){
    $src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_name);
} 
else if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) == 'gif') {
    $src_image = imagecreatefromgif($file_name);
}
else if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) == 'png') {
    $src_image = imagecreatefrompng($file_name);
}

imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);
imagejpeg($dst_image, "new.jpg");

?>
```

When I crop the image, it works with jpg but not with png or gif. All it shows is a blank picture. I'm certain there is something wrong with the if statements. What is the problem here? If I do it individually, without the if statements, it works no problem, and yes, I want my ouput to be jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you made a mistake here.

```
else if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) == 'png') {
   $src_image = imagecreatefromgif($file_name);
}
```

Should be :

```
else if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) == 'png') {
   $src_image = imagecreatefrompng($file_name);
}
```

and for there must be a separate if statement.

```
if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) == 'jpg, jpeg'){
   $src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_name);
}
```